# Meta tables in lua and_index function

Tags: lua

```
__index = function(tbl, key)    
    local a = tbl[key]    
    if a <=0 then a = 0 end    
    if a > 5 then a = 0 end   
    return a
end
```

Book says:
Though the preceding code looks very innocent and tries to keep the value of the element in the table within a range, this code will cause problems and circular references. The first line in the function, a = tbl[key], will actually trigger another index function call, and that in turn will invoke another, and so on.

But how is a = tbl[key] calling another index at every call ?

Comment: Because `tbl[key]` will trigger the same `__index` event.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff : What I intended to ask was, why this chain ? that index gets called and then in turn it calls another index function.Why is that ?

Comment: @Simrankaur It is because if a table has a metatable with `__index` metamethod and Lua can't find a key in the table, it invokes the `__index` lookup. If it is in fact a table, invoking `__index` means that the key does not exist. Therefore, calling `tbl[key]` again is certain to trigger `__index` metamethod once more and then once more, and...

Comment: @Simrankaur - There is no difference between generating indexing events in Lua code inside `__index` handler and outside it.

Comment: @W.B. : Thank you, do you mean that if metatable does not has that field either, it results in a loop by continually calling it ?

Comment: @Simrankaur no, no, see the edit to my answer. Lua does not scan metatable for that key at all. It scans the metatable only for the `__index` field. It would look for the key in the metatable **only** if the `__index` field of the metatable would point to **the metatable itself**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a bit wierd thing to do. Lua triggers `__index` metamethod only if it can't find a field in the table. Therefore, using `tbl[key]` inside it makes absolutely no sense at all. Unless `tbl` is not a table.

Anyhow, if you want to access a table's field from within `__index`, use `rawget`. That will ensure that no metamethods are called.

**EDIT:**

Let me explain how `__index` lookup works:

Let's assume the table has a metatable with `__index` defined.

If Lua can't find the key in the table, it looks for the `__index` field in the metatable. It does not look for the key itself. Then, if the `__index` is a table, it looks for the key in that table (not the metatable, although it is common to associate the metatable itself with its `__index` field). If it is a function, it is invoked with two parameters: `table` (initial table, not the metatable) and the `key`.

So if the `__index` metamethod is called, you can be certain that the initial table does not have that field defined. Therefore, when you try to index it again (as the first argument is the original table that triggered the index lookup), the story begins anew -> Lua can't find the key, it invokes the `__index` and so on.

Comment: :Yes, totally agree with you about the rawget but I am confused about the fact of chaining here, index is being called in chain with a=tbl[key], metatables are called when it can not find a field in table and that's when index is a table but here we have index as a function, the book clearly says : When the index function is called, it is passed two parameters: the Table and the Key.