# Editing multidimensional table with uncertain dimensions in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I want to be able to access and edit values in a user-generated table, that can have any number of dimensions.

Say, for this nested table,

```
table = {
    '1',
    {
        '2.1',
        '2.2'
    },
    {
        {
            '3.1.1',
            '3.1.2'
        },
        '3.2'
    },
}
```

I would have another table that contains a location for the needed data,

```
loc = {3, 1, 2}
```

Ideally, what I'd want is to be able to not only access but edit the values in the table, similar to using `table[3][1][2]` but by utilizing the `loc` table,

```
print(table[loc[1]][loc[2]][loc[3]]) --returns 3.1.2
print(table[loc]) --hypothetically something like this that takes each indexed member of the table in order
```

I also want to be able to edit this table.

```
table[loc] = {'3.1.2.1', '3.1.2.2'}
```

I need to be able to edit the global table, so cannot use the methods listed in [this reddit thread,](https://www.reddit.com/r/lua/comments/9m2phh/syntax_help_referring_to_to_values_in_nested/) and haven't been able to find the right way to use metatables for this yet. I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: maybe the index function might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980959/meta-tables-in-lua-and-index-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply write an additional function for this purpose.

```
function TreeGetValue (Tree, Location)

  local CorrectTree = true
  local Index       = 1
  local Dimensions  = #Location
  local SubTable    = Tree
  local Value

  -- Find the most deep table according to location
  while (CorrectTree and (Index < Dimensions)) do
    local IndexedValue = SubTable[Location[Index]]
    if (type(IndexedValue) == "table") then
      SubTable = IndexedValue
      Index    = Index + 1
    else
      CorrectTree = false
    end
  end

  -- Get the last value, regarless of the type
  if CorrectTree then
    Value = SubTable[Location[Index]]
  end
  
  return Value
end
```

Here, we assume that the tree is well-formatted as the beginning. If we find any problem we set the flag `CorrectTree` to false in order to stop immediately.

We need to make sure we have a `table` at every dimension in order index a value from.

```
> TreeGetValue(table, loc)
3.1.2
```

Obviously, it's also easy to to write the `set` function:

```
function TreeSetValue (Tree, Location, NewValue)

  local Index      = 1
  local Dimensions = #Location
  local SubTable   = Tree

  -- Find the most deep table according to location
  while (Index < Dimensions) do
    local IndexedValue = SubTable[Location[Index]]

    -- Create a new sub-table if necessary
    if (IndexedValue == nil) then
      IndexedValue = {}
      SubTable[Location[Index]] = IndexedValue
    end

    SubTable = IndexedValue
    Index    = Index + 1
  end

  -- Set or replace the previous value
  SubTable[Location[Index]] = NewValue
end
```

And then to test it with your test data:

```
> TreeGetValue(table, loc)
3.1.2
> TreeSetValue(table, loc, "NEW-VALUE")
> TreeGetValue(table, loc)
NEW-VALUE
```